# Delete multiple rows by multiple conditions in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a simple dataset:

[image]

I want to delete the rows where count>1 when animal is cat or dog. So the output should look like:

[image]

Can I get the result in an efficient way?  Thank you

Comment: Your sample output doesn't match your sample condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
count_mask = dataset['count'] > 1
animal_mask = dataset['animal'].isin(['cat', 'dog'])

dataset = dataset[~(count_mask & animal_mask)]
```